# Connected to a wired network but no internet

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I am connected to a wired network(an ethernet cable from my router).Ubuntu shows connected to "wired network 1" but in firefox it shows no internet connection.

When I am on windows,internet works fine.Also internet works fine on other computers connected to router running on windows.

I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: open up a terminal window  ctrl+alt+t   and issue   sudo service network-manager restart   ... which will bounce your network stack

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to make a ping to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)?

Open up a terminal window `ctrl+alt+t` and issue ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

if this don't work, try ping **8.8.8.8**

If the result of ping **8.8.8.8** or **[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)** is

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=27.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=27.0 ms
...
```

press Ctrl+C to stop and then review the Firefox proxy options in configuration.

If the second ping works and the first don't, you have trouble with your DNS.

If the first ping to google.com works, then:

In Firefox(version 56), go to **Preferences-> General -> Network Proxy -> Configure how Firefox connects to the Internet -> and click in settings.**

Then configure with your options. if you don't have proxy, select "No Proxy".

If this don't work. Check if you have a default gateway.

Go back to the command line and type: `sudo route -n`
You will see something like this.

```
Destination  Gateway      Genmask     Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface 
0.0.0.0      Router IP     0.0.0.0     UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
169.254.0.0  0.0.0.0     255.255.0.0   U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
192.168..... 0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0 U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

if you don't have **0.0.0.0 route**, then you don't have outgoing traffic to the internet, and then you need to review the network interface settings (maybe you have manual IP misconfiguration)